# Unable to connect to a domain network using Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, networking, domain

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium and I am unable to connect to our company's  network.

When I try to connect I get prompted to enter my username and password. However, I cannot add a domain. The `domain\` prefix is automatically populated with my local desktop computer name.

Is this feature not available? Why does it force it with a local computer only? Can this be changed in the registry? Is there a group policy change that I can configure?

Right now I use VPN but it gets extremely slow.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to connect a Windows 7 Home Premium PC to a domain.

For Domain connectivity you would have to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional or Windows 7 Ultimate.

Microsoft's comparison site is here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/compare

As you can see, Domain Join is only available on Professional and Ultimate.

What you *can* do, though, is use your local user/password to log into the PC, but provide alternate (Domain) credentials to map drives from Domain servers.  This is done by selecting "Connect using different credentials" in the "Map Network Drive" dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Although windows 7 and 8 will not allow the setting to be used. the following link will get you connected to server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713510.aspx

This will not allow you to use a remote connection on a home device. Unless using a web based java connection tool. Such as Juniper Networks. My company uses this and we can connect with any version of windows. It is very costly but works very well.

Hope this helps